# NgRx Data updateOneInCache change class to object

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-data

If I use updateOneInCache, then after that any class is converted to an object.
With using removeOneFromCache and after addOneToCache this doesn't happen. How can I fix this when I use the updateOneInCache?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fix this. One of the key concepts is that state should be stored serializable, a class instance is not serializable. See the [redux styleguide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions) for more info.